# Candlestick Plot Using Segments Command in R

Tags: r, plot, segments

I'm trying to make candlestick plots from OHLC data using R.  I need to be able to control the visual output, so I'm using a slight variation from Daniel Kovach's YouTube tutorial, which is a really good example, to build them from scratch.  When I try to get the candlesticks to plot, nothing appears on my graph.  This code works when I create a time series manually, but not when I use the getSymbols command.  I suspect it has something to do with the way the x coordinate is handled, but I just cannot seem to figure it out.  Here's my code:

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("SPY")
[1] "SPY"
df <- last(SPY[],10)
df
           SPY.Open SPY.High SPY.Low SPY.Close SPY.Volume SPY.Adjusted
2018-09-05   289.41   289.64  287.89    289.03   72452400       289.03
2018-09-06   289.15   289.49  287.00    288.16   65909900       288.16
2018-09-07   286.98   288.70  286.71    287.60   73524800       287.60
2018-09-10   288.74   289.04  287.88    288.10   50210900       288.10
2018-09-11   287.37   289.55  286.98    289.05   50530500       289.05
2018-09-12   289.06   289.80  288.23    289.12   59810800       289.12
2018-09-13   290.32   291.04  290.00    290.83   51034200       290.83
2018-09-14   291.06   291.27  290.00    290.88   55079900       290.88
2018-09-17   290.82   290.86  289.03    289.34   68244000       289.34
2018-09-18   289.58   291.58  289.55    290.91   61865000       290.91
plot (df[,1])
j=index(df)
segments (x0=j, y0=df[,2], x1=j, y1=df[,3], col="black")
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't have much luck, sorry. I'd suggest building your own plot e.g.

```
plot(index(df), df[,1], type = "p", ylab = "", xlab = "",
     ylim = range(df[,1:3]), main = "Title")
axis(1, at=round(unique(df[,1:3]), 0))
grid()
segments (x0=index(df), y0=df[,2], 
          x1=index(df), y1=df[,3])
lines(index(df), df[,1], lwd = 2)
```

`plot.xts` is just `plot` but with some additions, which can be replicated, albeit not in the exact way

or if you want to make it more fancy, check out `ggplot2` package, plenty of tutorials online